# .gitignore exception is including extra files

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I have .gitignore file as:

```
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/
!MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth.dll
```

For some reason source tree showing "MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth.dll" in commit list and some other files like;

```
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/AutoMapper.xml
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/Castle.Core.xml
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/Castle.Windsor.xml
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.xml
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth.dll
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth.dll.config
```

If I remove second line file ignore file it removes everything in this case (as expected). All I want is to include "MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth.dll"

It is doing a wildcard match or something? and ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to reinclude a file if a parent directory of that file has been excluded, q.v. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309) from @VonC.

So what you should have done is this:

```
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/**
!MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/**/
!MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug/MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth.dll
```

The first line ignores all files inside the `bin` directory, recursively.
The second line excludes all *folders* inside the `bin` directory, recursively.
The third line excludes the file which you want to be able to commit.

Comment: @dubes Thanks for the upvote.  VonC is a serious Git expert, easily one of the most knowledgeable people on this site.

Comment: Loved this approach. Thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually, on Git the most knowledgeable people would be torek (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) ;) As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152945/6309, complete with six (6!) footnotes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I hate to do this. (Answer own question in 5 minutes) but all I had to include sub-folder in ignore list like;

```
MyCompany.MyProject.OAuth/bin/Debug
```